# Debian Squeeze RAID 5 Install?

Tags: debian, system-installation, lvm, raid

I have a box with four Hard Drives on it. I am going to install Debian Squeeze (I know it's old... I have to) on it. I want to be able to treat the the four Hard Drives as a single Harddrive. Durringt he installation, I tried using LVM to join all 4 of my drives but then it complains about there not being a boot partition. How can I get around this issue???

Comment: Older versions of GRUB had problems with booting from LVM/software RAID. I am not sure if that is the problem here. The usual solution for that was to simply have /boot on a separate, regular partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think LVM in Squeeze supported RAID5. Only mirror and append (no redundancy).

This is from memory—I'm not running through this while typing it:

In the Debian Installer, partition each disk to have a ~256MB partition and a second partition that is the rest of the disk. Set the usage for both partitions (all 8 of them, in total) to "physical volume for RAID". Set the 256MB partition to bootable.

Next, create two RAID arrays: (1) a RAID1 array, with all four 256MB partitions. (2) a RAID5 [or whatever] array with the other four partitions.

Set the usage of the RAID5 array to "physical volume for LVM". (Unless you want full-disk crypto, in which case physical volume for crypto, and passphrase. Then set up the crypto disks, and use that as a physical volume for LVM.)

Go ahead and create a volume group out of the RAID5 array, and create a logical volume for rootfs (and whatever else).

Go ahead and select the LV for your rootfs, pick a filesystem type, and pick the mount point `/`

Set the usage of the RAID1 array to ext2 (no reason to use anything else, really, though ext3 and ext4 will both work), and make it `/boot`. (I don't recall if the Squeeze installer had the bug where it'll forget mountpoints if that's not the last thing you set up, but just in case, that's why you're doing this step now, not earlier).

Pick finish, and continue the install. When prompted, install grub in the MBR. If it lets you, install in the MBR of all four disks. Otherwise, you'll want to do that after rebooting.